# 2 Joomla databases per environment

Tags: php, database, joomla

I would like to configure a Joomla environment (1) with 2 different databases in 2 different servers so that every time new content is added, both databases are updated. I already thought about the dependencies file-wise that this would represent but I would really like to know if this achievable.

Thanks

Comment: You need MySQL replication, there's nothing that Joomla can do

Comment: So there's no way to duplicate the queries to point to both dbs? -weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may give you a starting point. http://docs.joomla.org/Connecting_to_an_external_database